# How to navigate between tabs in Fireworks CS6 with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: adobe-fireworks, shortcuts

Is there a shortcut for switching tabs in Fireworks CS6?

In case it's important, I´m using a mac with a Spanish keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help: [Fireworks - Select and customize keyboard shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d9a7-7ff8.html).

Fireworks lets you use keyboard shortcuts to select menu commands, select tools from the Tools panel, and speed up miscellaneous tasks that do not exist as menu commands.

**Select a shortcut set**

- Select *Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts* (Windows) or Fireworks > Keyboard
  Shortcuts (Mac OS).
- Select a shortcut set from the Current Set pop-up menu, and click OK.

**Create custom and secondary shortcuts**

You can create custom keyboard shortcuts from a preinstalled set, and you can create secondary shortcuts to include several different ways to perform an action.

The keyboard shortcuts except for menu commands cannot include modifier keys: Control, Shift, and Alt (Windows) or Command, Shift, Option, and Control (Mac OS). They must consist of a single letter or number key only.

- Select *Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts* (Windows) or Fireworks > Keyboard
  Shortcuts (Mac OS).
- Click the Duplicate Set button.
- Enter a name for the custom set and click OK.
- Select the appropriate shortcut category from the Commands list.
- Click in the Press Key text box, and press the desired keys for the
  new shortcut on the keyboard.

To add a secondary shortcut to the shortcut list, click the Add A New Shortcut (+) button. Otherwise, click Change to replace the selected shortcut.

Also, [here's a list of the current shortcuts](http://labs.kortina.net/posts/adobe-fireworks-cs5-keyboard-shortcuts/).

Answer (score 1):

It's control + command + "< / >" key

thanks anyway!